# how to show android bitmapdrawable change on next clickevents

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview, android-bitmap, bitmapdrawable

On next click when user inputs text, previous text on image is gone.  How to save all text inputs on bitmap drawable on all click events. Please suggest.

```
onCreate() {

    ImageView mView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dstImageView);
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic2);
    mView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
    mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                showNameDialog();

    }
}

private void showNameDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Photo Tag");
    alert.setMessage("Tag Message");
    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      Editable value = input.getText();
      // Do something with value!
        ImageView mView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dstImageView); 
      myDrawable test=   writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.pic2,value.toString(),touchxpos,touchypos);
      mView3.setImageDrawable(myDrawabletest);
      }
    });

//  write text on drawable
private BitmapDrawable writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text,float xPos,float yPos) 
 {
     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
     Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD);
     Paint paint = new Paint();
     paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
     paint.setColor(Color.RED);
     paint.setTypeface(tf);
     paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
     paint.setTextSize(11);
     Rect textRect = new Rect();
     paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
     canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);
     return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
}
```

How do i save the texts on bitmapdrawable for each click. Every time the previous text is getting replaced with latest one??

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `writeTextOnDrawable()` you are returning a new `Drawable` so the previous one is getting discarded. You need to have a function where you can pass an existing `Drawable` as reference like so:

```
private BitmapDrawable writeTextOnDrawable(BitmapDrawable existingDrawable, int drawableId, String text,float xPos,float yPos) 
 {
 Bitmap bm;
 if (existingDrawable == null) {
  bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
 } else {
  bm = existingDrawable.getBitmap();
 }
 Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD);
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
 paint.setColor(Color.RED);
 paint.setTypeface(tf);
 paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
 paint.setTextSize(11);
 Rect textRect = new Rect();
 paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
 canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);
 return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
}
```

Note however that this will just write text over the existing one because the `paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);` remains the same. You will need to control that yourself if you want the new text to be put under the existing one.

Comment: Can you suggest how to define a existingDrawable in my activity class assuming i have res id ? i am looking for sample implementation.

Comment: You have it already. It's your `myDrawable` which you can just pass as parameter to the function I shared.

Comment: did you mean like this?                                                           myDrawabletest= writeTextOnDrawable((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable,R.drawable.pic2,value.toString(),touchxpos,touchypos);  problem is myDrawable  is of type Drawable not  BitmapDrawable.So it fails. Type casting does not help.

Comment: Also myDrawable is defined inside onCreate(), which i can not access in showNameDialog() .inside it you suggested to call . can you tell how to access it?

Comment: my sample implementation:  public class phototag extends Activity {
 

    private int imgHeight, imgWidth; 
    Bitmap bmp;
 
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic2);  // global now  ***************************   call myDrawable = writeTextOnDrawable( (BitmapDrawable)myDrawable,R.drawable.pic2,value.toString(),touchxpos,touchypos);  // type casted.. application is crashing while launch.. can you tell what is wrong here???

Comment: Change `Drawable myDrawable` to `BitmapDrawable myDrawable`.

Comment: its not working when i use global BitmapDrawable myDrawable and pass it  to writeTextOnDrawable().. please suggest..any other way?